# Отправить svg файл по почте

Tags: java, android

Создал svg файл, нужно его отправить по почте, но я что-то делаю не так:

```
File file=new File(getFilesDir(), FILENAME);
    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

   if (file.exists()) {
       email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{etMail.getText().toString()});
       email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+file));
       email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
       email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
       email.setType("message/rfc822");
      // email.setType("*/*");
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Выберите email клиент :"));}
```

Приложение падает по строке

```
 email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+file));
```

с ошибкой:

> android.os.FileUriExposedException:
>   file:///data/user/0/ru.test/files/file.svg exposed beyond app
>   through ClipData.Item.getUri()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с API 24 (по моему) запрещается использование в `Intent` ссылок типа `file://`, необходимо их маскировать специальным `FileProvider`, который умеет превращать ссылки `file://` в `content://`

Инструкции [здесь](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing)